# Nested setInterval javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a JS code like this

```
function Entry(){
  var Trigger = setInterval(function () {
      var ent = EntryZone(); //EntryZone is a function which returns a value that change in every second
      if (Value <= ent) { // Value is a variable
        clearInterval(Trigger); 
        var TakeEntry = setInterval(function () {
          var chkPer = Percentage(); //Percentage() is a function which returns a value that change in every second
            if (Value >= chkPer) { //Here I am comparing Value with chkPer
              var interval = setInterval(function(){    
                if (Value >= chkPer){ //Here I want to compare Vlaue again with chkPer after 10 seconds. If it has still the same or grater value then proceeding further.
                  BuyNow();
                  clearInterval(TakeEntry);
                }
                clearInterval(interval);
              },10000);
            }
        }, 500);
      }
  }, 500);
}
```

Ok, so that is what I am trying to do. But as I run the script its messing up. The Middle part where I want to check the value again after 10 seconds is executing multiple time. I just want to execute it once. And if the value is not same after 10 seconds then clear the "interval" interval and go back and continue "TakeEntry" interval.
Please guide me what is wrong with the code. Thank you!

Comment: this is going to start a million intervals, over and over and over. Pretty sure that's not what you want, so before you show your code, explain what it is you actually wanted to achieve, then show the code, then explain _how_ you think it was supposed to achieve what you wanted.

Comment: the "middle part" should be setTimout instead of an interval, seems like the answer to your question for me

Comment: @john can you please edit the code with setTimeout. I already tried that but had the same output.

Comment: You know ... setInterval doesn't execute exactly at 500ms, but both setInterval and setTimeout is executed _after_ 500ms. So if you check twice per second, that means the value will sometimes not be checked for a second, and you will "miss out" on that value change. Instead, I suggestion to set a variable and then send out an event that executes your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this sort of code is a lot easier to write correctly with [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) instead of setInterval.  Here's what I believe you meant from your description, but you could easily modify the code to e.g. trigger `Entry` again in certain situations.  The idea is that, at any moment, at most one of the three functions should have a timeout scheduled.

```js
function Entry(){
  setTimeout(function () {
    var ent = EntryZone(); //EntryZone is a function which returns a value that change in every second
    if (Value <= ent) { // Value is a variable
      TakeEntry();
    } else {
      Entry();
    }
  }, 500);
}
function TakeEntry(){
  setTimeout(function () {
    var chkPer = Percentage(); //Percentage() is a function which returns a value that change in every second
    if (Value >= chkPer) { //Here I am comparing Value with chkPer
      Check10();
    } else {
      TakeEntry();
    }
  }, 500);
}
function Check10(){
  setTimeout(function(){    
    if (Value >= chkPer){ //Here I want to compare Value again with chkPer after 10 seconds. If it has still the same or grater value then proceeding further.
      BuyNow();
    } else {
      TakeEntry();
    }
  }, 10000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the call to `setInterval( ....., 10000)` is not stopping the other interval to keep on ticking...

This kind of logic is much easier to implement with `async` `await` syntax:

```
// Utility function to await a given delay:
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function entry() {
    while (true) { // Keep doing?
        var ent = EntryZone();
        while (Value > ent) {
            await delay(500);
            ent = EntryZone();
        }
        while (true) {
            var chkPer = Percentage();
            if (Value >= chkPer) {
                await delay(10000);
                chkPer = Percentage();
                if (Value >= chkPer) {
                    BuyNow();
                    break;
                }
            }
            await delay(500);
        }
    }
}
```